# Context-dependent text classification (HMM, CRF, ANN or something else)

Tags: neural-network, hidden-markov-models, text-classification, markov-chains, crf

My goal is to build a text classification system that is used to understand and possibly automate a popular coding instrument that is used in Education for coding student forum messages.

The coding scheme has four codes (T,E,I,R) and each online forum message can be assigned only one of them. Those codes represent a stage in student's learning cycle, and it is theorized by a model that students learning goes through those four stages which are reflected in their messages. We have 1750 messages that are coded by human coders and we would like to build a model that can provide insights into what defines each of these phases (T,E,I and R).

Our original goal was to build a "typical" classifier based on various features we thought are important. However, we would like to include somehow the "thread context", as the answers (and their content) are dependent on the previous messages. Basically, I would like to somehow take into the account the class of the previous message in the discussion and also the previous message of a given author. something like this:

[image]

Now, I'm just starting this and exploring different ideas how to model this problem. I was thinking of somehow using hidden markov models for this, and was wondering am I on the right track?

The thing is that our states are not unknown, given that this is labeled dataset, we know the states and would like to estimate transition and emission probabilities and then use them for classification on "unknown data" (held out fold or really new messages)

Also, we have multiple observations for each state, and depending on the features we will use, we might have a large number of text-extracted features

Finally,  each state depends on two previous states: 1) state of the previous message in the thread, and 2) previous state of the author. I'm not sure can this be modeled somehow :)

EDIT: I've learned about Conditional Random Fields, and they for now, seem a better fit for this kind of problems, any words of advice about them? :)